# Running two Bootstrap 3 collapse with one handler

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/dbdLwpv3/). I want to find out how I can run this two collapses with one click, doesn't matter on A1 or A2 but collapses both `.panel-collapse` for A1 and A2?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          A 1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
     A 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          B 1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        B 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          C 1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        C 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          A 2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
     A 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          B 2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        B 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          C 2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        C 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this by using classes rather than IDs in your data-parent and href tags.

Here's an updated fiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/Lj4Lqkkz/

By the way, your html has some duplicate IDs. IDs should be unique. You may want to fix this or you might experience some other problems.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" class="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion" href=".collapseOne">
          A 1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in collapseOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
     A 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion" href=".collapseTwo">
          B 1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse collapseTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        B 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion" href=".collapseThree">
          C 1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse collapseThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        C 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" class="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion" href=".collapseOne">
          A 2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in collapseOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
     A 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion" href=".collapseTwo">
          B 2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse collapseTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        B 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion" href=".collapseThree">
          C 2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse collapseThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        C 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

  </div>
</div>
```